# Calling a function when iterating over a hash

Tags: ruby

Ok, this might be really crazy, and/or stupid but..

I am writing an ircbot in Ruby to learn the language and I want to include a dispatcher for commands in the bot.

So let's say that I have a hash that defines which command that belongs to what function:

```
hash = { ".voice" => "basic", ".op" => "basic" }
```

And then I do this:

```
hash.each_pair do |k,v|
 case content[0]
  when k then v(content[1])
 end
end
```

Where content[0] is ".voice" and content[1] is the one being voiced.

This generates an error telling me that v is an undefined method for main:Object.

Is what I'm trying to do making any sense or is there a better way to do this? And if this way of doing this makes sense.. why does it return with that error?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are trying to do. The error you are getting is because `v` is a string. Are you trying to set `v = content[1]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a method, and the method's name in a string:

```
def basic(v)
  puts v
end

method_name = 'basic'
```

If you do this:

```
method_name('Hello')
```

You'll get your error

```
undefined method `method_name' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

You have to make the string into a method object to be able to use it:

```
method_object = method(method_name)
method_object.call('Hello!')
```

Comment: Accepted.. I'm new here so it seems that I cannot upvote, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Change...

```
 v(content[1])
```

to...

```
 send(v, content[1])
```